# Is using an Orison (cleric) considered to be a free action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, free-action

I am new to Pathfinders.  Is using an Orison a free action, or does it count as a standard action?

Answer (score 6):

### It depends on the spell itself

Casting time does not depend on the spell level, every particular spell has its casting time specified in the description. Most orisons have "1 standard action" as their casting time. See [Create Water](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/createWater.html) for example:

> **CREATE WATER**
>
> **School** conjuration (creation) [water]; **Level** cleric 0, druid 0, paladin 1
>
> **Casting Time** 1 standard action

However, there are orisons with a longer casting time, like [Mending](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/mending.html):

> **MENDING**
>
> **School** transmutation; **Level** bard 0, cleric 0, druid 0, sorcerer/wizard 0
>
> **Casting Time** 10 minutes

Comment: I would add that orisons are submitted to all standard spell casting rule. Accept they don't burn spell slots.

Comment: @3C273 Thats "Except" not "Accept".